# how to get names from an XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm making a small application that creates batch rendering scripts, its all going well and does all its supposed to do but I've hit a brick wall
The batch tool converts a scene file which is encrypted to XML file with only the camera names, so what I'm trying to do is retrieve the camera names from a file called temp.xml 
In the XML it looks like this:

```
<Object Identifier="./Cameras/## Current View ##" Label="Standard Camera" Name="## Current View ##" Type="Camera">
```

I need to get ## Current View ## and any other camera and add them to a list box

I hope this isn't to vague at the moment the process is
The user enters a scene name, save path
they can either enter camera names manually or press a button, which  launches the render software by command line loads the scene with arguments (strips out all the model, lights textures info etc) and saves a tiny xml with a few render options and camera info.. that bit works but I've about fried my brain lol

If the camera was in between `<> </>` I know how to do that I think I'm just over complicating matters hence why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to deal with a XML file, the best thing you can do is relying on the XMLReader class. Here you have an example of how to use it with your information:

```
    Dim path As String = "path of the XML file"
    Dim settings As System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings = New System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    Using reader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(path)
        While (reader.Read())
            if (reader.NodeType = System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) Then
                If (reader.Name = "Object") Then

                    Dim wholeAttribute As String 'Whole string as contained in the XML attribute
                    Dim betweenHashes As String 'String between #'s


                    'From "Identifier"
                    wholeAttribute = reader.GetAttribute("Identifier")
                    If (wholeAttribute IsNot Nothing And wholeAttribute.Trim.Length > 0) Then
                        If (wholeAttribute.Contains("#")) Then
                            betweenHashes = wholeAttribute.Substring(wholeAttribute.IndexOf("#"), wholeAttribute.LastIndexOf("#") - wholeAttribute.IndexOf("#") + 1)
                            betweenHashes = betweenHashes.Replace("#", "").Trim()
                        Else
                            betweenHashes = wholeAttribute
                        End If
                    End If

                    'From "Name"
                    wholeAttribute = reader.GetAttribute("Name")
                    If (wholeAttribute IsNot Nothing And wholeAttribute.Trim.Length > 0) Then
                        If (wholeAttribute.Contains("#")) Then
                            betweenHashes = wholeAttribute.Replace("#", "").Trim()
                        Else
                            betweenHashes = wholeAttribute
                        End If
                    End If


                    'Adding the string to ListBox1
                    If (betweenHashes IsNot Nothing And betweenHashes.Trim.Length > 0) Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(betweenHashes)
                    End If


                End If
            End If
        End While
   End Using
```

As you can see, the code above retrieves what you want from two different places. I guess that this is information more than enough to help you to understand how to deal with the XML parsing in VB.NET.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm not on my pc which has VS but I think the problem is going to be that object is used for other things the xml looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26539256/test.xml
Thanks again it looks very close

Comment: If the XML follows a proper structure there shouldn't be any problem. What this code does is looking for the attributes of "Object". If you assign "Identifier" or "Name" as attributes of "Object" and give different meanings to them in different parts, this code wouldn't work; but also wouldn't work any other approach (as far as it would be a bit difficult to tell what means what). Thus, this is the proper way to access "Identifier" or "Name": firstly, analysing the XML node ("Object") and then checking whether its attributes match what you want or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to get my head around this

`code`
'Adding the string to ListBox1
                        If (betweenHashes IsNot Nothing And betweenHashes.Trim.Length > 0) Then
                            ListBox1.Items.Add(betweenHashes)
                        End If
'code'
Kick out a runtime error, Start index can not be zero

Comment: I don't know your specific conditions, this is just a sample code. First thing you should do is checking if the value is parsed correctly from the XML, that is, wholeAttribute and betweenHashes and not blank. In any case the error you report does not sound to be related with this line (unless having a problem with ListBox1?!). This sounds related with the Substring parts; most likely because of using them with a string not containing "#". I will perform the modification right now; in any case, bear in mind that you should adapt my code to your situation.

Comment: I have adapted the code. Now it checks whether the given string contains # or not. Please, understand the code and don't just use it blindly; bear in mind that I am getting the same string from two different locations: it is just to show you different alternatives. This code is not expected to be used "as it is", but just to be taken as a reference to get some grasp about how to deal with XML reading in VB.NET

Comment: Hi varocarbas, I really appreciate your efforts, there is a link to the xml above or I can post a section here

The camera between hashes is the default camera, every other camera is whatever the user names them, the frustrating thing is I have an AutoIT version of this tool but its useless without the connected render engine

Comment: I have tested the original XML file and now it should work without any problem. Bear in mind that I have accounted for # because I thought that this was used every time; from the original XML file, I understand that it is used exceptionally. My code provides a good first step to understand how to deal with your problem, extend it as much as required to accomplish exactly what you want. Also bear in mind that the XML parsing is pretty simplistic; you might also want to improve it further.

Comment: Thank you for your time  varocarbas its been a great help, the runtime error has gone and objects are being listed :)

I'm not a coder, this project has been on going awhile, I keep trying to make it better and testing myself more

Comment: No problem. Today you have got enough information, perhaps not to become a pro coder, but at least to start creating small programs :)

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression `//Object/@Name` will return all the camera names.