# Adding multiple strings to a listbox from text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, listbox

I have a text file I need to get multiple strings from, I can sort of do it but it only shows the first string in the listbox

When we tried with XML reader it was collecting everything in the XML that was tagged Object Identifier along with the cameras

I need to look for lines similar to the following, there could be any amount

Object Identifier="./Cameras/MyCamera" Label="Standard Camera" Name="MyCamera" Type="Camera"

key identifiers:

./Cameras/

Label="Standard Camera"

Type="Camera"

I could use "MyCamera" after ./Cameras/  or Name="MyCamera" both of these are common in each occurrence of the lines

in my example below it has the file I wish to read it should list 3 cameras
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy7r2auf9vv0m7g/testvb.zip

The XML is generated by Thea render, its the scene file with the model, lights etc taken out so it just leaves cameras and some core settings

Thanks to  varocarbas, this is the code that solves my problem:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\jen\Desktop\test\temp.xml"
    Dim settings As System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings = New System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    Using reader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(path)
        While (reader.Read())
            If (reader.NodeType = System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) Then
                If (reader.Name = "Object") Then

                    'Object Identifier="./Cameras/MyCamera" Label="Standard Camera" Name="MyCamera" Type="Camera"
                    Dim Identifier As String = reader.GetAttribute("Identifier") '"./Cameras/MyCamera"
                    Dim Label As String = reader.GetAttribute("Label") '"Standard Camera"
                    Dim Name As String = reader.GetAttribute("Name") '"MyCamera"
                    Dim Type As String = reader.GetAttribute("Type") '"Camera"

                    Dim wholeString As String = Name  'WHOLE STRING TO BE ADDED TO THE LISTBOX

                    'Adding the string to ListBox1
                    If (wholeString.Trim.Length > 0) And Type = "Camera" Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(wholeString)
                    End If


                End If
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: String is not an array.  In C# it is String[].  Not sure about VB.  Then the array will be the datasource

Comment: @Blam the VB.NET equivalent is String() but he is actually not returning an array, but a single string as far as does not return the array generated by split but one of its positions. Actually he is over-complicating it and is using split twice and returning the first position resulting from the second splitting action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `XMLReader` I proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497495/how-to-get-names-from-an-xml-file/17501387#17501387) and do the following modifications on it:

```
Dim path As String = "temp.txt"
Dim settings As System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings = New System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings()
settings.ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment
Using reader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(path)
    While (reader.Read())
        If (reader.NodeType = System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) Then
            If (reader.Name = "Object") Then

                'Object Identifier="./Cameras/MyCamera" Label="Standard Camera" Name="MyCamera" Type="Camera"
                Dim Identifier As String = reader.GetAttribute("Identifier") '"./Cameras/MyCamera"
                Dim Label As String = reader.GetAttribute("Label") '"Standard Camera"
                Dim Name As String = reader.GetAttribute("Name") '"MyCamera"
                Dim Type As String = reader.GetAttribute("Type") '"Camera"

                Dim wholeString As String = Identifier & " - " & Label & " - " & Name & " - " & Type 'WHOLE STRING TO BE ADDED TO THE LISTBOX

                'Adding the string to ListBox1
                If (wholeString.Trim.Length > 0) Then
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(wholeString)
                End If


            End If
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

This code retrieves all the information you want and stores it in `LisBox1` by putting " - " to separate each element. This is information more than enough and you should be the one performing any further change, for example: converting "./Cameras/MyCamera" into "./Cameras/" (there is an indication of how to do that in my previous code); or change the way the different items are displayed in the `listBox` (or perhaps you want to include one listBox per element: one for identifiers, another for labels, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the text after """ Label" the text is in between "./Cameras/Camera" Label its just the word Camera and any other that may be in the text if it makes life easier I can do a quick example? thanks again

Comment: Here's an example https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26539256/batchcreator/testvb.zip
 only ## Current View ##. Camera, Camera #2 should show in the list

Comment: @NigeC lots of things wrong with your approach. Firstly you are considering the whole file as a string and thus will never get the performance you want; you have to go line by line. Additionally, the best way to deal with XML files is System.XML; actually, this example sounds quite familiar to me :) haven't I answered a previous XML-related question about it? Anyway... I will update my answer with a SHORT sample showing you how to face the problem in the way you want; BUT, in your position, I would start doing things step-by-step instead of taking codes without understanding what they do.

Comment: @NigeC I have read right now my previous answer regarding the XMLReader an it represents, undoubtedly, the best solution for this problem. What split does is dividing one string on account of a specific character/set of characters. Example: 1,2,3 -> split(',') returs an array with 3 elements. It might be OK if the "dividing character" is clearly defined and the text structure is not too complex, otherwise it wouldn't be the best approach. In your case, you cannot get anything just with split, you have to do string analysis after each split. XMLReader makes things much, much easier.

Comment: @NigeC could you please explain me the exact outputs you want to get (saying just "only ## Current View ##. Camera, Camera #2" is not too descriptive) and why you are not using the suggested XML option? Go to the first line you want to retrieve and say EXACTLY the words which you want to include in the listview.

Comment: @NigeC also, please, update your answer by including the text you want to parse. If you put just the code (I, or anyone else) will intend to correct it by assuming that the taken approach is right; but your approach to the problem is completely wrong.

Comment: In the file there could be any number of "Cameras", within the XML, with the XML version it was listing everything that was and Object as well as the cameras.
the line: <Object Identifier="./Cameras/Camera" Label="Standard Camera" Name="Camera" Type="Camera">
The camera is named twice in that line ie after ./Camera/ also Name=""

Comment: @NigeC trust me, XMLReader is (by far) the best approach for this. Please, describe in as much detail as possible what you want to accomplish exactly (you can update your answer, rather than explaining it via comments) and I will advise you how to proceed.

Comment: ok will do, its really difficult to explain, the reason why I tried the text approach is an earlier version of my app used AutoIT and I just treated it as a text file and it wasn't that hard

Comment: @NigeC if you want to treat it as strings, you would have to rely on text analysis (firstly splitting, then finding out the indices and the associated substrings; by bearing in mind the different names you want to bring into account). By relying on XMLReader, the required steps will be lower in any case. You have to understand that the input text is complicated and thus there is no immediate solution (but one being easier to be implemented). If you are looking for advice you shouldn't try to advise the advisor. Please, describe, at least, one line in detail.

Comment: I wasn't trying to advise the advisor varocarbas, sorry if it sounded that way, I'm just trying my best to explain I'm a 3D artist not a coder and I'm doing this to learn something, this is the only thing I'm struggling with and I'm grateful for all the time you've put in helping me, If you think it'll be better with XML reader then I'll go back to that, I just couldn't figure out how to extend the filter even more

Comment: @NigeC no problem at all. But you should try a bit harder to transmit the ideas clearer, such that I can answer quicker and more efficiently. Please, update your answer by including the following: 1. full text of the file; 2. One line completely analysed; for example: this is the first line bla, bla -> I want to take "the first line" and the second "bla" and include this in the listBox; if there would be a third "bla" I would also want it in the listbox. Ideally you should do this analysis with a second line in case of having another behaviour. Let me know when you are done.

Comment: Hopefully I've explained it right above, I also posted a picture of what the thing actually looks like

Comment: @NigeC you have include lots of information with no use to help you (please, delete it); also you should remove the original code you posted as far as it does not represent the proper way to face this problem. I have updated my answer and, as you can see, you just need to do small modifications on the XMLReader to get all what you want. Bear in mind that the point of this site is helping PROGRAMMERS with clearly-defined problems which might be helpful to others. You cannot come here without any knowledge and expecting someone to perform a custom development for you (...)

Comment: @NigeC (out of space in my previous comment)... if you don't want this answer to be cancelled by the admins (because of going completely against what this site is about), update it as suggested: remove all the useless bits and focus your question on how to retrieve the specific information from the file (by using the XMLReader from my previous answer). If still you cannot deal with the remaining problems (editing strings, adding items to listBox differently), you should post one question per problem (or, ideally, learn to code or HIRE a programmer). I hope that everything is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you, I except there is a bit of "selective" learning" here, I asked because I was stuck, I thought I might of found a easier solution going the text file route obviously I was wrong, Thanks for looking at this, if you look at the xml file "Object" appears about 10 times so I get more than cameras, which was the original issue, I didn't go back to the original post as I didn't want to waste your time.. thanks again sorry for the trouble

Comment: @NigeC You are welcome. If you want to learn/improve, being wrong is never a problem.

Comment: Is it possible to filter further? Object Idenifier appears for other things, so maybe I need to do a filter by type a well.
I included my xml in the original post, Its quite a bigfile I don't think I can post its content.. I realise you probably don't want to download but it explains a lot.. sorry about typos this laptop sucks!!

Comment: @NigeC if you seriously want to learn you would have to start doing things by yourn own instead of asking. The XMLReader is a quite programmer-friendly format and thus you don't even need to do research just try things. If you analyse carefully my code and relate it with your file you would understand that there are two realities: node ("Object" or "Parameter") and attributes ("Identifier", "Label", etc.) for each node. With this code you have a first approach to deal with both realities. Logically things can get more difficult (e.g., nested nodes) and this is where the programmer comes in :)

Comment: A BIG thank you, I now have it working, i just added:
 If (wholeString.Trim.Length > 0) And Type = "Camera" Then... and it just lists what I needed. Thank you for your time, I don't know why I couldn't get my head around this.. its so simple when yo know how lol